# Symfony. Cache Component. Does not return CacheItemInterface

Tags: php, symfony, redis

I don't know why it's happening. I have this code. I've got it from here https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html

```
private function createCacheItem(string $key): CacheItemInterface {
    return $this->cache->get($key, function (ItemInterface $item) {
        return $item;
    });
}
```

And in the local machine, it's OK. But in production, I have sometimes this error.

Return value must be of type Psr\Cache\CacheItemInterface, int returned.

I see that this function get(), return a mixed value. But how to avoid this error?

Comment: Does your `createCacheItem` method do more than what you’ve posted?

Answer (score 0):

Your function’s return type isn’t correct. Based on your sample it should be an `int` but you could also just remove it.

```php
private function createCacheItem(string $key) {
    return $this->cache->get($key, function (ItemInterface $item) {
        return $item;
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not helping. Because i work with this "item" further.

$item =  $this->createCacheItem($key);
$item->set($value);

I need this object

Comment: In the _inner_ function you work on that item. The outer method itself will return the result of `get` which is your _final_ item, possibly the result of an HTTP request or a database query or other. That's why `get` shows as mixed for the return type. But `get` won't return anything of a `CacheItemInterface` or `ItemInterface`, unless something weird is going on.